# How to remove edges of HalfPlane

Tags: graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

`EdgeForm[]` does not work.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Green, Opacity[0.2],HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {0, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Any idea how to remove edges of `HalfPlane`

Comment: That seems sort of bug-ish, since in the documentation for `HalfPlane`, it says that "Graphics rendering is affected by directives such as FaceForm, EdgeForm, Opacity, and color."

Comment: `EdgeForm[Transparent]` is another possible workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me, since `HalfPlane` responds to other `EdgeForm` directives. For example, in the following `HalfPlane` responds to `EdgeForm[Red]`.

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[Red], Green, Opacity[0.2], Disk[], HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {0, 1}]}]
```

[image: red-edge]

A work-around is

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[Red], Green, Opacity[0.2], Disk[], 
  EdgeForm[Transparent], HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {0, 1}]}]
```

[image: no-edge]